# Group a vector in a rolling fashion

Tags: r

I have some years with length N. For e.g.

```
yearVec <- 1980:2019
```

I want to group years such that each group has 4 years which are rolling

```
group1 1980:1983
group2 1981:1984
group3 1982:1985
.
.
.
groupN 2016:2019
```

Preferably in a list like below

```
[[1]]
[1] 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983

[[2]]
[1] 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984

[[3]]
[1] 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985

[[4]]
[1] 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986

[[5]]
[1] 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987
```

Comment: `Map(seq, head(yearVec, -4), tail(yearVec, -4))`

Comment: `Map(seq, head(yearVec, -3), tail(yearVec, -3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lapply`:

```
lapply(yearVec, function(x) x:(x + 4))[seq(length(yearVec) - 4)]
[[1]]
[1] 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984

[[2]]
[1] 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985

[[3]]
[1] 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986

[[4]]
[1] 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987

...etc
```